# Moving to a tab and a specific location within that tab

Tags: html, css, tabs

I have a page with a link on, and three tabs. Default view is Tab 1

The tabs are below the page fold

The end result should be that, when the person clicks on the link, it should open Tab3 and move the page up so that the user can view the content of the tab.

As it stands now, the user clicks on the link and it opens the tab3, but because the tabs are below the page fold, it seems like nothing is happening.

I want the screen to move down to the tab as well. Im currently using onClick="parent.location='#contact'" to open the tab

This is the code for the link

```
<form>
<input class="listbutton" type="button" onClick="parent.location='{site_url}
{url_title text="`$action_object->m_listing_info->title`"}/
{route_suffix for="listings"}{$action_object->m_listing_info->listing_id}#contact'"
value="{translate text='contact_owner'}" title="{translate
text='listestablishmentforfree'}">
</form>
```

This is the code where it's linking to

```
<li>
<a href="#contact"><span>{translate text='contact_owner'}</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: A good idea UI-wise would be to *put the controls (tab bar) next to the thing they control (the content)*. Apart from that, how can we help if you don't provide any code?

Answer (score 0):

As you did not have code, so what i can understand i am helping u

```
       $('#anchorID').click(function() {               
    $("#contacts").focus();
});
```

Comment: Okay, so i've added the code in my original posts ;-) Thanks again